# fabric don't start twisted application as a daemon

Tags: python, twisted, fabric, twistd

I have written a simple automation script for deploying and restarting my twisted application on remote Debian host. But I have an issue with starting using twistd.
I have a `run.tac` file and start my application as follows inside fabric task:

```
@task
def start():
    run("twistd -y run.tac")
```

And then just `fab -H host_name start`. It works great on `localhost` but when I want to start application on remote host I get nothing. I can see in log file that application is actually launched, but `factory` is not started. I've also checked `netstat -l` - nothing is listening my port.
I've tried to run in non-daemon mode, like so `twistd -ny run.tac`, and, voila, factory started and I can see it in `netstat -l` on remote host. But that is not the way I want it to work cause it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was an issue reported sometime back which is similar to this.

- [Init scripts frequently fail to start their daemons](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/395)
- [init-scripts-dont-work](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/blob/611133c88f7603d6f15bcf316cfe9e248b6858b8/docs/faq.rst#init-scripts-dont-work)

It also suggested that it seems to succeed with the option `pty=False`. Can you try and check that?

```
run("twistd -y run.tac", pty=False)
```

Some more pointers from the FaQ:

- [why-can-t-i-run-programs-in-the-background-with-it-makes-fabric-hang](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.2/faq.html#why-can-t-i-run-programs-in-the-background-with-it-makes-fabric-hang)

Comment: `pty=False` helped. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's actually got it's own section in the [FAQ](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.2/faq.html#init-scripts-don-t-work).

Comment: @Morgan: Yes, the second link is exactly the same!